# List within lists within lists

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a list called Countries, and each country has a list of Towns, which in it's turn has a list of Streets. And a street has a number of houses. Lists within lists within lists. Very simple.

I need to generate a list of houses that are located in countries which names start with the letter 'A'. Not a very logical example, but it's easier to explain than the more complex structure I'm dealing with.

This is, of course, not too complex and could be done by creating a List and then ForEaching all countries.Where(Name.StartsWith('A')), then ForEaching all towns and finally adding each street in that town to the list.

I don't like that method so I want something prettier...

Could this be done by using something like Aggregate on the Countries.Where() list? If so, how? (Thus, in a single statement.)

Yes, the selection will be on the top list only, so that should make it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for Enumerable.SelectMany (which allows you to ungroup one level of hierarchy):

```
List<County> countyList = GetCounties();

IEnumerable<County> aCounties = countyList
  .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("A"));

List<House> aCountyHouses = aCounties
  .SelectMany(c => c.Towns)
  .SelectMany(t => t.Streets)
  .SelectMany(s => s.Houses)
  .ToList();
```